# color gradient does not show

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to write a pH scale in html, colours included. I want the colours to smoothly transition from acidic to alkaline (top to bottom of scale.). However, the pH colours don't show. Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel = "STYLESHEET" type = "text/css" href = "Ph.css">
    <title >Ph SCALE</title>
    <h1 class = "Ph">THE pH SCALE</h1>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p class = "zero">0.0 very acidic</p>
        <p class = "one">1.0</p>
        <p class = "two">2.0</p>
        <p class = "three">3.0</p>
        <p class = "four">4.0</p>
        <p class = "five">5.0</p>
        <p class = "six">6.0</p>
        <p class = "seven">7.0 neutral</p>
        <p class = "eight">8.0</p>
        <p class = "nine">9.0</p>
        <p class = "ten">10.0</p>
        <p class = "eleven">11.0</p>
        <p class = "twelve">12.0</p>
        <p class = "thirteen">13.0</p>
        <p class = "fourteen">14.0 very alkaline</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following is my CSS code. I used -webkit-gradient for the colour gradient:

```
* {
     background-color: #ccc;
 }

 h1.Ph {
     background-color: white; font-family: Arial; padding: 20px; 
     text-decoration:underline;
     text-align: center;
 }

 p {
    padding: 5px; margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
 }

 div {
    background-color: -webkit-gradient(top, bottom,rgb(238,62,128), rgb(0,136,221));
    font-family: Courier;
 }
```

Can you please explain why there's no colour gradient from the top to the bottom of `<div>`?

Gratefully
saad

Comment: you shouldn't put `<h1 class = "Ph">THE pH SCALE</h1>` in the `head` but in the `body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradients are not a value of the `background-color` but of the the `background-image`

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgb(238,62,128), rgb(0,136,221));
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/L6bQ9/

Answer (score 0):

use `background-image` instead of `background-color` and it works